# Camera orientation and focal length from two 3D points and known position

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I'm trying to determine camera orientation and focal length given camera position and two 3D-2D points correspondences (4 degrees of freedom → 2x2D points).

My reference camera orientation is towards positive world z axis, with x and y camera coordinates equal to x and y world coordinates. The image plane of the reference camera (in both the world and the camera reference frames) is
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
  [-0.5,0.5]\\
  [-0.5,0.5] \\
f
\end{array}
\right) $$

Known data:

- 3D world coordinates of two points, $$ \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    x_i\\
    y_i \\
  z_i
  \end{array}
  \right) $$
- 2D coordinates of those two points on the image plane (i.e. X and Y coordinates of those points in the camera reference frame, the Z coordinate being the unknown focal length f)
- Camera position in world coordinates,
  $$ \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    x_C\\
    y_C \\
  z_C
  \end{array}
  \right) $$

How can I retrieve the focal length and the rotation matrix?
Thank you!

Comment: Please explain the meaning of the notation for the image plane.

Comment: I'm assuming a square 1x1 image sensor, parallel to Oxy, centered around the world z axis and at distance f from the origin. In principle the sensor size is not required for a solution of the problem, but I use it to relate an actual image to this model.

Comment: Specifically, what are you trying to convey by what look like intervals in the first two slots of the image plane “vector?”

Comment: I'm trying to convey that the coordinates of all the points of the imaging sensor (in the original non-rotated position) are in the form (x,y,f), with x and y in the interval [-0.5, 0.5]. I think this is not strictly relevant to the estimation problem, which doesn't rely on the sensor size.

Comment: It’s certainly irrelevant to the specification of the image plane, which I now gather is the usual $z=f$.

Comment: I think one possible way to go could be a parametric Orthogonal Procrustes-style solution with a later distances-constrained estimation of the unknown focal length, but I couldn't find any work related to that...

Comment: What do you mean by “x and y camera coordinates equal to x and y world coordinates?” This appears to contradict the later facts that the camera has an arbitrary rotation about the $z$-axis and is located at an arbitrary location in world coordinates.

Comment: At any rate, you need either further assumptions about the camera or a third point correspondence. The known camera position and axis direction account for only five of the eleven degrees of freedom of the projection matrix. E.g., square pixels and no skew would lock down another two degrees of freedom.

Comment: I mean that the starting camera position, i.e. relative to which I am computing the rotation, is the one where the x and y coordinates in the camera reference frame correspond to the world coordinates. I'm basically putting a costraint on the orientation around the optical axis. And yes, I am assuming square pixels and no skew, so two points should be enough. In fact I have managed to determine the focal length from the conservation of the angle between the two rays in the camera coordinates and the world coordinates.